# Steps to getting a CA signed certificate

Tags: java, security, certificate, signed

What steps should I take to obtain a CA signed certificate that verifies a public key used to do create digital signatures?
One constraint is whatever coding that's needed will need to be done in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what kind of signatures is needed, you should be looking for different certificates, eg. [code signing](http://www.globalsign.com/code-signing/) or [office doc signing](http://www.globalsign.com/microsoft-marketplace/) or other types they offer. By following the links you will learn all details about the procedure.

In brief - on your client computer (usually via browser) you generate a keypair that consists of the private key and a public key. Then the public key is embedded into Certificate Signing Request (CSR), which is sent to the CA (again usually via browser). And the CA sends you a signed certificate, which you then merge with your private key.

Answer (score 0):

to create your own certificate you can use java keytool:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/keytool.html

greets

Answer (score 0):

You need to contact a Certificate Authority for that.  Verisign, etc.  They each have a process to acquire one of these.  unless I am misunderstanding your question